# Unity gaming services _LeaderBoard_I want to replace the player id with a player name that the player gonna write

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, leaderboard

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Unity.Services.Authentication;
using Unity.Services.Core;
using Unity.Services.Leaderboards;
using UnityEngine;

public class LeaderboardsSample : MonoBehaviour
{
    const string LeaderboardId = "IQ_Leaderboard";
    string VersionId { get; set; }
    int Offset { get; set; }
    int Limit { get; set; }
    int RangeLimit { get; set; }
    List<string> FriendIds { get; set; }
    string playerName;

    async void Awake()
    {
        await UnityServices.InitializeAsync();
        await SignInAnonymously();
    }

    async Task SignInAnonymously()
    {
        AuthenticationService.Instance.SignedIn += () =>
        {
            Debug.Log("Signed in as: " + AuthenticationService.Instance.PlayerId);
        };
        AuthenticationService.Instance.SignInFailed += s =>
        {
            // Take some action here...
            Debug.Log(s);
        };

        await AuthenticationService.Instance.SignInAnonymouslyAsync();
    }

    public async void AddScore(double score)
    {
        var scoreResponse = await LeaderboardsService.Instance.AddPlayerScoreAsync(LeaderboardId, score);
        Debug.Log(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(scoreResponse));
    }

    public async void GetScores()
    {
        var scoresResponse =
            await LeaderboardsService.Instance.GetScoresAsync(LeaderboardId);
        Debug.Log(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(scoresResponse));
    }

    public async void GetPaginatedScores()
    {
        Offset = 10;
        Limit = 10;
        var scoresResponse =
            await LeaderboardsService.Instance.GetScoresAsync(LeaderboardId, new GetScoresOptions{Offset = Offset, Limit = Limit});
        Debug.Log(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(scoresResponse));
    }

    public async void GetPlayerScore()
    {
        var scoreResponse =
            await LeaderboardsService.Instance.GetPlayerScoreAsync(LeaderboardId);
        Debug.Log(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(scoreResponse));
    }

    public async void GetPlayerRange()
    {
        var scoresResponse =
            await LeaderboardsService.Instance.GetPlayerRangeAsync(LeaderboardId, new GetPlayerRangeOptions{RangeLimit = RangeLimit});
        Debug.Log(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(scoresResponse));
    }

    public async void GetScoresByPlayerIds()
    {
        var scoresResponse =
            await LeaderboardsService.Instance.GetScoresByPlayerIdsAsync(LeaderboardId, FriendIds);
        Debug.Log(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(scoresResponse));
    }

    // If the Leaderboard has been reset and the existing scores were archived,
    // this call will return the list of archived versions available to read from,
    // in reverse chronological order (so e.g. the first entry is the archived version
    // containing the most recent scores)
    public async void GetVersions()
    {
        var versionResponse =
            await LeaderboardsService.Instance.GetVersionsAsync(LeaderboardId);

        // As an example, get the ID of the most recently archived Leaderboard version
        VersionId = versionResponse.Results[0].Id;
        Debug.Log(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(versionResponse));
    }

    public async void GetVersionScores()
    {
        var scoresResponse =
            await LeaderboardsService.Instance.GetVersionScoresAsync(LeaderboardId, VersionId);
        Debug.Log(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(scoresResponse));
    }

    public async void GetPaginatedVersionScores()
    {
        Offset = 10;
        Limit = 10;
        var scoresResponse =
            await LeaderboardsService.Instance.GetVersionScoresAsync(LeaderboardId, VersionId, new    GetVersionScoresOptions{Offset = Offset, Limit = Limit});
        Debug.Log(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(scoresResponse));
    }

    public async void GetPlayerVersionScore()
    {
        var scoreResponse =
            await LeaderboardsService.Instance.GetVersionPlayerScoreAsync(LeaderboardId, VersionId);
        Debug.Log(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(scoreResponse));
    }
}
```

I am following the unity docs to implement an online leaderboard system in my 3d android game, but in the UI I want to display a player name and his score and rang.

I have search for 1 day ON THIS TOPIC AND GOT NOTHING RELATED TO IT , BTW THIS LEADERBOARD SERVICES STILL IN BETA VERSION FROM UNITY GAMING SERVICES

The problem right now is I can't modify any data related to the player name because there is nothing about it - can you help me with this ?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem.
You need to update the Authentication player name.

Here's how you can achieve this:

```
await AuthenticationService.Instance
        .UpdatePlayerNameAsync("YourName");
```

Pay attention that you can't use spaces when updating.